# CreateCommand works while SqlQueryRaw doesn't

Tags: c#, database, sqlite, entity-framework-core

Getting row count I managed to get, but why the other approach doesn't work? I am using SQLite with Microsoft's SQLite extension for Entity Framework Core.

This works :

```
using (var db = new DBConnection())
{
    foreach (var table in db.Model.GetEntityTypes())
    {
        await using var cmd = db.Database.GetDbConnection().CreateCommand();
        cmd.CommandText = $"SELECT COUNT(*) FROM {table.Name.Split(".").Last()}";
        await db.Database.OpenConnectionAsync();
        var count = await cmd.ExecuteScalarAsync();

       Console.WriteLine(count);
    }
}
```

This doesn't :

```
using (var db = new DBConnection())
{
    foreach (var table in db.Model.GetEntityTypes())
    {
        var query = db.Database.SqlQueryRaw<int>("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM {0}", $"SELECT COUNT(*) FROM {0}",{table.Name.Split(".").Last()});

        var count = query.Single();

       Console.WriteLine(count);
    }
}
```

What did I do wrong?

Comment: When you say the second approach doesn't work, what exactly do you see? An exception? The wrong return value?

Answer (score 0):

Could you try the following? The second approach contains duplicate `select` statements.

```
var tableName = table.Name.Split(".").Last();
var query = db.Database.SqlQueryRaw<int>($"SELECT COUNT(*) FROM {tableName}").ToList();
```

Be very careful when [using](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/sql-queries) FromSqlRaw, and always make sure values are either from a safe origin, or are properly sanitized. SQL injection attacks can have disasterous consequences for your application.

Answer (score 0):

Somehow you've mis-interpreted the way the second method handles the parameters for the query. Let's break it down:

- Template: `"SELECT COUNT(*) FROM {0}"`
- Parameter 0: `$"SELECT COUNT(*) FROM {0}"`

  - Because you have prefixed this with a dollar sign, the value in the curly braces is treated as an expression, which gives the value `0`. So this becomes `"SELECT COUNT(*) FROM 0"`
- Parameter 1: `{table.Name.Split(".").Last()}`

  - The curly braces around this aren't needed, and I'm not sure that would compile as-is.

When EF executes this, it takes the template and replaces `{0}` with the value in parameter 0. So you would end up executing the following statement:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM SELECT COUNT(*) FROM 0
```

I think you'd be looking for something like:

```
db.Database.SqlQueryRaw<int>("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM {0}", table.Name.Split(".").Last());
```